# How can I search for string in Mysql field ingoring any special characters in the field?

Tags: mysql, regex

Say I have the search string 'mens health' and in my database I have the field with value 'men's health', how can I match my search string against this perhaps using regex?  Bearing in mind, this is just one example and in my database there are many records that also contain any number of non alpha characters such as "/,$,',-,(,),1,2..."?  The search string is obtained from the URL and should not contain any encoding as to be easily read.

Comment: Why not just use `=` for a perfect match?

Comment: There's no "regex substition" in MySQL.   I solved this problem by writing a MySQL function to output a sanitized version of  the string.   The function steps through the source string character by character and builds the result.

Comment: Similar to @JoshGreifer solution, I've had stored a sanitized copy of the field in the database but mine was heavily cluttered with some bbml-like syntax and citations. Since I knew it was going to be a problem every single time someone searched, I went with that route. That was an SQL Server database, but that's irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a little function which generates a regex string which I used with an RLIKE in my MySQL Query which should match the sequence of alpha numeric characters regardless of any special characters between the letters.

```
function GenerateCategoryRegex($SrchTerm) {
    $arrChar = str_split(str_replace(' ', '', $SrchTerm));
    $RegEx = '(^|;)+[[:space:]]*';
    foreach($arrChar as $Char) {
        $RegEx .= $Char . '{1}[^\w,]*';
    }
    $RegEx .= '[[:space:]]*(;|$)+';

    return $RegEx;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add another column that contains the "searchable text", such as "mens health".  Then search *that* column, but display the *original* column ("mean's health").

Now you are free to do other tweaks -- such as adding synonyms, common misspellings, etc. to the search column.

And your `REGEXP` can become a simple `LIKE`, or *probably* even a *fast* `FULLTEXT`.